# Https connection closed by peer in android 5.0 lollipop

Tags: java, android, https, socat

I am trying to implement an android application.Therefore,  I've called a web-service `HTTPS`.However, I  am not able to get the response data.It showing an error

> " connection closed by peer "

Here is my code for `HTTPS`:

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);

    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}
}
```

Here's the code which I wrote for DefaultHttpClient:

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                .getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

For getting response:

```
public static String getData(final HttpPost httpost) throws IOException,
        URISyntaxException {

    String inputLine = "Error";
    final StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    {

        InputStream ins = null;

        ins = HTTPHandler.getUrlData(httpost);

        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

    }

    return buf.toString();

}
```

I would like to ask you for any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you don't want to publish the url so please check the backend with https://www.ssllabs.com and tell us what is "bad" if you don't have an A rating.

Comment: I can't understand about your point.you want to know the connection base url?@rekire

Comment: Yeah, I could guess that there is something wrong with the certificate or the cipher suites.

Comment: @ rekire,Can you help to me how i used cipher suites.Can you give to me a example source code.How i will cipher suites in my code.

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing a similar error