# Https connection finish with Connection closed by peer on Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, boringssl

I have a problem with communication over SSL (TSL) between Android device (Samsung Galaxy with Android 6.0) and Simple Java App which is using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer. I have to say that on other device with Android 4.4 everything works fine.

When Android 6.0 tries to make handshake, server side finishes communication,  on android a see bellow stacktrace

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:212)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1322)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1410) 
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:466)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447) 
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468) 08-28 06:47:21.322 3676-5603/pl.com.szb.gateopener W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118) 08-28 06:47:21.322 3676-5603/pl.com.szb.gateopener W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpsServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(HttpsServiceConnectionSE.java:127)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.sendData(HttpTransportSE.java:292) 
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:184)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118) 
W/System.err:     at pl.com.szb.gateopener.client.PSBGOImplPortBinding.sendRequest(PSBGOImplPortBinding.java:99)
W/System.err:     at pl.com.szb.gateopener.client.PSBGOImplPortBinding.execute(PSBGOImplPortBinding.java:284)
W/System.err:     at pl.com.szb.gateopener.client.PSBGOImplPortBinding.getGates(PSBGOImplPortBinding.java:142)
W/System.err:     at pl.com.szb.gateopener.client.PSBGOImplPortBinding$2.Func(PSBGOImplPortBinding.java:165)
W/System.err:     at pl.com.szb.gateopener.client.PSBGOImplPortBinding$2.Func(PSBGOImplPortBinding.java:163)
W/System.err:     at pl.com.szb.gateopener.client.PSBGOImplPortBinding$7.doInBackground(PSBGOImplPortBinding.java:318)
W/System.err:     at pl.com.szb.gateopener.client.PSBGOImplPortBinding$7.doInBackground(PSBGOImplPortBinding.java:308)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Android Code for SSL initiation

```
 `private void initSSL() throws Exception {
    Log.d(TAG,"initSSL");
    TrustManager tm = new CustomX509TrustManager();
    SSLContext customSSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");
    customSSLContext.init(null , new TrustManager[] { tm } , null);
    sslSocketFactory = customSSLContext.getSocketFactory();

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Verifying %s , sessionId: %s", hostname, Arrays.toString(session.getId())));
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
}


public class CustomX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    private String TAG = "CustomX509TrustManager";
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkClientTrusted");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkServerTrusted");
        // Here you can verify the servers certificate. (e.g. against one which is stored on mobile device)

        InputStream inStream = null;
        try {
            inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.goserver_10y);
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
            inStream.close();

            for (X509Certificate cert : certs) {
                // Verifing by public key
                cert.verify(ca.getPublicKey());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
            throw new CertificateException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getAcceptedIssuers");
        return null;
    }
}`
```

And a server code:

```
`private void initServer() throws Exception{
    Config config = getContext().system().settings().config();
    host = getConfigString("pl.com.szb.GOImpl.host", config, "0.0.0.0");
    port = getConfigInt("port", config, 10000);
    useSSL = getConfigBoolean("use_ssl", config, true);
    endpointLocation = getConfigString("endpointLocation", config, "/go");

    String fullURL = String.format("%s://%s:%d%s",(useSSL ? "https" : "http"), host, port, endpointLocation);
    log.info(String.format("WSDL : %s?wsdl", fullURL));

    if (useSSL) {
        keystorePass = getConfigString("keystorePass", config, "secret");
        keystoreName = getConfigString("keystoreName", config, "second/server.bks");

        char[] pass = keystorePass.toCharArray();
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(keystoreName);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        ks.load(is, pass);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
        kmf.init(ks, pass);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 0);

        ((HttpsServer)server).setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {
            public void configure(HttpsParameters params) {
                try {
                    log.debug(String.format("Got client: %s, wantAuth: %b, needAuth: %b",
                        params.getClientAddress().toString(),
                        params.getWantClientAuth(),
                        params.getNeedClientAuth()
                    ));

                    params.setWantClientAuth(false);
                    params.setNeedClientAuth(false);

                    //what to do more??

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.warn(String.format("Failed to create HTTPS port, cause " + ex.getMessage()));
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 0);
    }
   server.setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    server.start();

    HttpContext httpContext = server.createContext(endpointLocation);
    endpoint = Endpoint.create(SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING,this);
    endpoint.publish(httpContext);
}
```

`

What i have checked:

- every link that google and stackoverflow suggest after the title was typed (especially link [Https connection closed by peer in android 5.0 lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872106/https-connection-closed-by-peer-in-android-5-0-lollipop) - but with no luck)
- Cipher siute on both devices and in theory both should be able to finish handshake. There are corresponded algorithms.
- I checked both communication with wireshark. I found that even if i delcare (in Android) TLSv1.2 version TLS 1.0 is send in SSL header(see  [attached wireshark dump](http://finni.projekty.pl/android_to_httpsserver.pcapng) - use 'Decode as' -> SSL) In line 140 we see communication from Android 6.0, Bellow (in line 145 we see working communication from Android 4.4) 10.0.0.203 is the Android 6.0, 10.0.0.99 is the server, 10.0.0.200 is the Android 4.4
- I read about 'Connection closed by peer' and in many topics guys are talking about wrong certificate, but in my case i think that SSL crashes during protocol negotiations not during certificate exchange (that comes later).

The server site is little bit old (it's a SOAP service) but i think that it's not important what the server serves.

Please help, it's my first post.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Android 6.0 trying to connect to my server using a self-signed certificate. Earlier Android versions work fine and so does Windows 7. Did you ever find a solution to this?